# C# - Is there a way to constrain two type parameters to be necessarily different?

Tags: c#, class, types, type-constraints

I'm building a `MyClass<T1, T2> : IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>>` class, but for it to make any kind of sense in the context of my application I need to ensure that `T1 != T2`.

Is there a proper way to constrain `T1` and `T2` so that they aren't the same type?

Comment: No.  Consider to throw an exception in the constructor, if really, really necessary.

Comment: What goes *disastrously wrong* if they do happen to be the same type? I can imagine all kinds of *pointless* activity that could occur (but that's on the consumer if they choose to do so) but cannot imagine any scenario where it would cause actual problems.

Comment: And that's even before considering whether you wish to rule out inheritance chains. I.e. if `T1` is derived from `T2`, are you also seeking to rule that out? Because unsealed classes by default would point to an obvious way to circumvent this constraint if a consumer chose to do so.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm trying to do a [bidirectional dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map) feel as ergonomic as I can, and to do so I made it such that `myBiDic[T1 myKey]` return the `T2` value associated with it and  `myBiDic[T2 myKey]` returns the `T1` value associated with it too. If `T1` and `T2` are the same `myBiDic[myKey]` would be ambiguous, because the program would not have be able to know which direction to map the value from. I know I could simply do something `myBiDic.Fowards[myKey]`, but as I said I'm trying to it as ergonomic as I can...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, type inheritance would make this a nightmare. My concept may simply be completely flawed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Also, since every traditional `Dictionary<Tkey, Tvalue>` method is mirrored for both `T1` and `T2` (for example, both `TryGetValue(T1 myKey, out T2 myVal)` and `TryGetValue(T2 myKey, out T1 myVal)` exists), equality between `T1` and `T2` would make `TryGetValue(myKey, out myVal)` ambiguous.

Comment: So as you've already observed, if you do this and specify the same type parameter, the indexers become ambiguous and so unusable, so nobody can accidentally use such a class in such a way and write code that will compile. Why did you feel the need to do any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what types they should be, you can use the [`where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) type constraint:

```
class MyClass<T1, T2> : IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>>
    where T1 : MyClass1
    where T2 : MyClass2
```

But there is no way to allow them to be any class, but enforce that they are not equal. You would have to throw an exception in the constructor maybe:

```
if (typeof(T1) == typeof(T2)) {
    throw new Exception("Types must not be the same.");
}
```